Nvidia GeForce 310 graphics card not compatible with GNOME 46
I have an Nvidia GeForce 310 graphics card that is not compatible with GNOME 46. Is there a solution? Note that it was working efficiently with GNOME 45.

The desktop Environment usually relies on the GPU drivers provided by the system / the Linux kernel.
Please edit your question and add details which Ubuntu release you are using, which Linux Kernel you are running and which graphics driver is used.

What do you mean by "not compatible"? The card is quite old - 15 years, give or take, so I wouldn't expect much of it.
